# catkin_make install and dynamic_reconfigure issue

Tags: catkin-make

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Hello,
I am getting this weird behavior under ROS Indigo:

- I am using dynamic_reconfigure: e.g. `cfg/Node.cfg`
- In CMakelists I am calling `generate_dynamic_reconfigure_options()`
- Files are generated nicely, e.g. `NodeConfig.h`
- `catkin_make` works
- Node works in general
- However when I do: `catkin_make install` I get an error that the file `NodeConfigConfig.h` is missing. So for some reason it adds another `Config` string to the generated header and naturally it cannot find it. Weird.

Any ideas what can been happening? I not getting this in other packages. And I don't know how to debug this...

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/279385/catkin_make-install-and-dynamic_reconfigure-issue/) by [tanasis](https://answers.ros.org/users/29349/tanasis/) on ROS Answers with karma: 97 on 2018-01-10

Post score: 0

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

See if #q203700 helps.

---

Originally posted by [gvdhoorn](https://answers.ros.org/users/5184/gvdhoorn/) with karma: 86574 on 2018-01-10

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 3

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [tanasis](https://answers.ros.org/users/29349/tanasis/) on 2018-01-10**:
Yes this was it. Name file and `.cfg` parameter name missmatch. Nasty error! Thanks!